# IE11 3d transformations and perspective

Tags: javascript, css, gsap

I have created a 3d block that I am animating with tweenmax.  I know that IE doesn't support transform-style: preserve-3d so you need to move it to the child, but because there are multiple blocks (more than the example) it doesn't really work especially when using the js to tween them.

My question is there a way to preserve the 3d using javascript for Internet Explorer?

http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/mhca1k10/2/

```
 .box {
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
}

.box::before,
.box::after,
.box i,
.box i::before,
.box i::after,
.box b {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.box::before {
  background: red;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(180deg) translate3D(-30px, 0px, 150px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(180deg) translate3D(-30px, 0px, 150px);
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(180deg) translate3D(-30px, 0px, 150px);
}

.box::after {
  background: pink;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  -ms-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(180deg) translate3D(-30px, 0px, -30px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(180deg) translate3D(-30px, 0px, -30px);
  transform: rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(180deg) translate3D(-30px, 0px, -30px);
}

.box i {
  background: green;
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0px);
  -webkit-transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0px);
  transform: translate3D(0, 0, 0px);
}

.box i::before {
  background: purple;
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translate3D(0, 0, -60px);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate3D(0, 0, -60px);
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate3D(0, 0, -60px);
}

.box i::after {
  background: orange;
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3D(0px, -30px, -30px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3D(0px, -30px, -30px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3D(0px, -30px, -30px);
}

.box b {
  background: silver;
  width: 180px;
  height: 60px;
  -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3D(0px, -30px, 30px);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3D(0px, -30px, 30px);
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translate3D(0px, -30px, 30px);
}
```

Comment: [3D Cube - IE transform-style: preserve-3d workaround](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/details/bdvya)

Comment: this won't keep the 3d when tweened, and also it only works when you use a transparency.

http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/mhca1k10/3/

Comment: These could help .. GSAP 3D Cube (cross browser and IE11) http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/FEbzA .. GSAP 3D Cube (cross browser and IE11) (rotateX relative tweens) http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/wMZrrP .. GSAP 3D Cube (cross browser and IE11) (rotation relative tweening) http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/yYvJoW .. For IE11 you need to animate each face separately to achieve 3D for the workaround